# Create an extra column in a panda dataframe where, if one or more rows are missing then the extra column will contain the column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, validation

I am trying to create a new column in df that contains a small description that says for each row these many columns are Nan.This is mainly for error logging purpose. I want to use the numpy.where condition to do that, but i don't want to specify the column names. if there a simple way to do that?

I did try using the np.where condition to do it but i am new to panda so i am getting errors.

Comment: Use `df['count na'] = df.isna().sum(axis=1)`

Comment: Use isna() or isnull().